Is the cross dimensional spider unique to Across the Spiderverse
The big reveal at the end of act 2 in Across the Spiderverse is that Miles' spider bite is given by a Spider from another universe, namely Earth-42.
The film itself uses various comic book universe designations such as Earth-65 for Spider Gwen. Specifically it uses Earth-1610 for Miles' home universe. In the comics 1610 is the Ultimate Marvel Universe.
Is this same cross dimensional spider used in the introduction of Miles Morales in the Ultimate Marvel comic line? The Wikipedia pages suggest not, but Wikipedia is not a reliable summary.

The universe names overlap from the films to the comics. They're not supposed to, but they do.

@Valorum across the Spiderverse appear to acknowledge this itself when name checking earth-199999
